# Why can't I take the squareroot of this complex equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, exponential-function

Let $w\in \Bbb{C}$. I want to solve $3=e^{2w}$ and find all solutions for $w$, so I don't need to choose a branch of logarithm. My first intuition was to direclty apply the logarithm to this equation. Then $2w=\log(3)+2\pi i k$. Hence $w=\frac{\log(3)}{2}+\pi i k$. But if I apply the squareroot first then $\sqrt{3}=e^w$. But then applying the logarithm we get $\log(\sqrt{3})+2\pi i k$. Here I am confused because I take $2\pi i k$ and not $\pi i k$. So I think I somehow miss some solutions. Where is my mistake?

Comment: A complex number has *two* square roots ...

Comment: If you apply $\sqrt{}$ then you must take the *two* square roots and get $\pm \sqrt 3 = e^w$ and then applying the log to $\sqrt 3$ you will get $w = \log\sqrt 3 + 2\pi i k$ and applying the log to $-\sqrt 3$ you will get  $\log \sqrt 3 + (2pi k + 1)i$.  Combining you get the correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When applying $\ln$, you considered all branches.  But you did not do this for the square root.  For square root, there are two branches which can be written as

$$\pm\sqrt{3} = e^w$$

Then applying $\ln$ and the two branches become:

$$\ln\sqrt{3} = w+2\pi ik\qquad\text{ or }\qquad\pi i+ \ln\sqrt{3} = w+2\pi ik$$
which can be coalesced to:

$$\ln\sqrt{3} = w+\pi ik$$
which is what you got via the first approach.